# Overrinde the functionality of a user-defined macro

Tags: macros

I want to add an option to the document class which will allow me to modify definition of a single macro.

The option which declares the macro

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{nicepaper}}{
\newcommand{\FOO}[1]{\baz[size=\small]{#1}\stepcounter{TODOCOUNT}}
}
```

Similarly via another class option I want to change the functionality of `\FOO` to do nothing: `\renewcommand{\FOO}{}`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

May be it's better if you do something like

```
\newcommand{\foo}{}

\DeclareOption{myoption}{%
...\renewcommand\foo{something} ...}
\DeclareOption{youroption}{%
...\renewcommand\foo{something else}...}
```

**example**

```
\newcommand{\foo}{}

\DeclareOption{myoption}{%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{nicepaper}}{%
\renewcommand{\FOO}[1]{\baz[size=\small]{#1}\stepcounter{TODOCOUNT}}
}{}}   % I add {} here
\DeclareOption{youroption}{\renewcommand\FOO{}}
```

Comment: sounds reasonable, but I would like to know how it can be done the way I asked... would you consider providing a minimal example for that too?

Comment: @KristofTak I add example

Comment: there is no need for `{` after `\renewcommand` in `\DeclareOption{youroption}{\renewcommand` ?

Comment: @KristofTak yes

Comment: @KristofTak `\renewcommand` reads the macro name argument as normal undelimited argument, which can be a token group with curly braces or a single token, the macro token in this case.